# How to interpret Seaborn's regplot() when using x_bins?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm walking through a course on Seaborn and I'm having trouble understanding how exactly the `x_bins` parameter in Seaborn's `seaborn.regplot()` function works.

The documentation has the below:

> Bin the x variable into discrete bins and then estimate the central tendency and a confidence interval. This binning only influences how the scatterplot is drawn; the regression is still fit to the original data. This parameter is interpreted either as the number of evenly-sized (not necessary spaced) bins or the positions of the bin centers.

So I understand that when I mention, say, `x_bins = 5`, seaborn will bin the X-axis such that there is an equal (as much as possible) number of observations in each bin. And if I mention something like `sns.regplot(data=mpg, x="weight", y="mpg", x_bins=np.arange(2000, 5500, 250), order=2)` (as given in the docs), the numbers are taken to be the bin centres.

My question: what exactly are the bin edges then? For example:

1. [In this figure from the docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Ky8.png), what are the first and second bins? Is it 1500 to some number between 1500 to 2,250?
2. In [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2VOR.png) (from a DataCamp course), produced through the code below (by specifying the number of bins), is the first bin 0.0 to ~0.25, and the second bin ~0.25 to somewhere under ~0.4?

I'm having trouble understanding the creation of bins and where exactly the point representing the mean is made.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of `x_bins` is implemented in function [bin_predictor](https://github.com/seaborn/seaborn/blob/d1c04f2c2c4dbd11ede016405b5ea51380e37f51/seaborn/regression.py#L318) in Seaborn's `regression.py`.

`x_bins` only determines at which positions the dots (default blue) and their error lines are drawn. These are drawn instead of the `x,y` positions of all inputs.

When `bins` is a number, the positions are calculated such that each bin gets about the same number of points.

To know to which bin a point belongs, the distance between each point and each bin is calculated. The point will belong to the nearest bin. So, the center between two bins defines the separation.

Here are two examples together with a scatter plot. The scatter plot is colored depending on the bins, following the code given in `bin_predictor()`.

The left plot uses an array to define the bins. The first bin goes from the minimum weight till the center between the first and second bin. So, from `1613` till `2125.0`. The second bin goes till `2375.0`.

The right plot calculates 5 bin positions. They are chosen as the quantiles at `1/6`, `2/6`, `3/6`, `4/6` and `5/6` of the weights. For this dataset, the values are `[2124.17, 2395.0, 2803.5, 3297.33,       3952.5]`. The first bin goes from `1613` till `2259.58`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

mpg = sns.load_dataset("mpg")
x = mpg["weight"]
y = mpg["mpg"]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))
for ax, bins in zip([ax1, ax2],
                    [np.arange(2000, 5500, 250), 5]):
    sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, x_bins=bins, order=2, ax=ax)

    if np.isscalar(bins):
        ax.set_title(f"x_bins = {bins}")
        percentiles = np.linspace(0, 100, bins + 2)[1:-1]
        bins = np.percentile(x, percentiles)
    else:
        ax.set_title("x_bins : given list of positions")
    dist = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(np.array(x), bins))
    bin_ids = np.argmin(dist, axis=1)
    palette = (['crimson', 'limegreen'] * 10)[:len(bins)]
    sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, hue=bin_ids, palette=palette, zorder=0, legend=False, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: visualizing x_bins for sns.regplot]